# Django replace ModelForm instance dynamically OR don't save Form data [image]

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms

data entry people keep adding and duplicating models because they can't easily search for an existing item inline so I added fields to the Brand ModelForm to allow autosuggesting a Brand model.

## The Problem

Brand.name is a required field by the Brand model. Thus when only the Autocomplete field is filled (in the case of reassigning an existing Brand to the current company) the form.save() fails (its empty but a Brand.name is required by save() and in any case I don't want to save the form as a model instance as I've just reassigned ).

If a Brand is submitted in the reassign field, I want to just set that Brands.company to the parent formset value, and silently return without trying to save the ModelForm.

The relation is a Foreign Key from Brand Model to the Company model - a company may have many Brands.

A picture says a thousand words so...

[image]

## Code

```
class BrandAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    reassign_existing = AutoCompleteSelectField('brand', required=False,)
    confirm_reassign = BooleanField(required=False, help_text=_("Are you sure you want to reassign the brand?"))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BrandAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].required = False

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(BrandAdminForm, self).clean()
        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()

        if cleaned_data['reassign_existing'] \
                and cleaned_data['confirm_reassign'] \
                and not self.instance.pk:
            self.instance = cleaned_data['reassign_existing']
            cleaned_data['reassign_existing'].company = self.instance.company
            cleaned_data['id'] = self.instance.id
            cleaned_data['category'] = self.instance.category.all()
            cleaned_data['website'] = self.instance.website
            cleaned_data['twitter_handle'] = self.instance.twitter_handle
            cleaned_data['wikipedia_uri'] = self.instance.wikipedia_uri
            cleaned_data['email'] = self.instance.email
            cleaned_data['name'] = self.instance.name
            return cleaned_data
        elif cleaned_data['reassign_existing'] \
                and cleaned_data['confirm_reassign'] \
                and self.instance.pk:
            raise forms.ValidationError("You can't reassign AND add/edit a brand in the same form. Clear one of the sections.")
        else:
            if not cleaned_data['name']:
                msg = u"You must add a name to a new brand."
                self._errors["name"] = self.error_class([msg])
            return cleaned_data
    class Meta:
        model = Brand
```

This approach almost works, only when reassigning a Brand's Categories are being list. This is M2M field.

## Edit 1

I tried to override the save to not save when there is value in 'reassign_existing' but end up with a

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'company_id'
```

this is the setup

```
class BrandAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
reassign_existing = AutoCompleteSelectField('brand', required=False,
                                            )
confirm_reassign = BooleanField(required=False, help_text=_("Are you sure you want to reassign the brand?"))

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(BrandAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['name'].required = False

def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(BrandAdminForm, self).clean()

    if cleaned_data['reassign_existing'] \
            and cleaned_data['confirm_reassign'] \
            and not self.instance.pk:
        cleaned_data['reassign_existing'].company = self.instance.company
        cleaned_data['reassign_existing'].save()
        return cleaned_data
    elif cleaned_data['reassign_existing'] \
            and cleaned_data['confirm_reassign'] \
            and self.instance.pk:
        raise forms.ValidationError("You can't reassign AND add/edit a brand in the same form. Clear one of the sections.")
    else:
        if not cleaned_data['name']:
            msg = u"You must add a name to a new brand."
            self._errors["name"] = self.error_class([msg])
        return cleaned_data

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.cleaned_data['reassign_existing']:
        super(BrandAdminForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Meta:
    model = Brand
```

Comment: After Edit one I had to override the Formset saving for new instances

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I came up with. Requires subclassing ModelForm and BaseFormsetInline

```
class BrandBaseFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
def save_new(self, form, commit=True):
    import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()
    if form.cleaned_data['reassign_existing'] \
            and form.cleaned_data['confirm_reassign'] \
            and not form.instance.pk:
        return form.cleaned_data['reassign_existing']
    else:
        import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()
        return super(BrandBaseFormSet, self).save_new(form, commit=commit)

class BrandAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
"""
Allow for reassigning of reverse fk relationships inline of the child.
"""
reassign_existing = AutoCompleteSelectField('brand', required=False)
confirm_reassign = BooleanField(required=False)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(BrandAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['name'].required = False

def clean(self):
    """
    Here we check if its a new form or reassigning an existing brand. If its reassigning, we just do that in
    this method.
    :return: cleaned form data
    """
    cleaned_data = super(BrandAdminForm, self).clean()
    if cleaned_data['reassign_existing'] \
            and cleaned_data['confirm_reassign'] \
            and not self.instance.pk:
        cleaned_data['reassign_existing'].company = self.instance.company
        cleaned_data['reassign_existing'].save()
        return cleaned_data
    elif cleaned_data['reassign_existing'] \
            and cleaned_data['confirm_reassign'] \
            and self.instance.pk:
        raise forms.ValidationError("You can't reassign AND add/edit a brand in the same form. Clear one of the sections.")
    else:
        if not cleaned_data['name']:
            msg = u"You must add a name to a new brand."
            self._errors["name"] = self.error_class([msg])
        return cleaned_data

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.cleaned_data['reassign_existing']:
        return super(BrandAdminForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    else:
        return self.cleaned_data['reassign_existing']

class Meta:
    model = Brand
```